# Combining columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine the columns of a dataframe like the following

```
df['new'] = df['a'].astype(str) + ':' + df.b.astype(str) + ' ' + df.c.astype(str)
```

When some entries in columns named `a`/`b`/`c` are empty it gives

```
df['new']=

sfg nan nan
nan nan nan
```

I'd like to know how to avoid nan's. Instead, I prefer to leave it empty.

Suggestions will be really appreciated.

Comment: Please post sample input with expected output for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) would help you

```
df = df.fillna('')
df['new'] = df['a'].astype(str) + ':' + df.b.astype(str) + ' ' + df.c.astype(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a general function around the concatenation

```
import pandas as pd

def concat_columns(inp,delimiter=':'):
    
    try:
        res = f'{delimiter}'.join(inp.values)
    except Exception:
        return ' '
    
     return res
```

```
df['new'] = df[['a','b','c']].apply(concat_columns,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing the `nan` string. And also, use apply for a bit cleaner code:

```
df['new'] = (df[['a','b','c']].astype(str)
                 .replace('nan', '')
                 .apply(lambda x: x['a'] + ':' + x['b'] + ' ' + x['c'], 
                        axis=1)
            )
```